# Socket IO sends message twice and get it again

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have two problems with SocketIO Chat. It seems that chat works fine but It sends twice(or more) chats.

**User1 Screenshot**
[image]

If User1 sends message it show like that. When I entered something it shows what I typed.

And the another problem is from User2. If User 2 Typed type something, it returned twice. And I tested User3 and it returned third times.. I don't know why it work like this.

**User 2 Screenshot**
[image]

**[Server Side Code]**

```
router.get(`/:userId/admin/contact`, function (req, res, next) {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  // console.log(io);
  console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms));
  let contactArray = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
  // Socket.io
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Join Room
    socket.join(`sangumee-Quarterican-KJ`);
    console.log(`JOIN : sangumee-Quarterican-KJ`)

    socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
      io.sockets.to('sangumee-Quarterican-KJ').emit('send:message', data.message);
      console.log(data.message);
    });
  });
  res.render('mypage/contact', {
    userId: userId,
    contactArray: contactArray
  })
});
```

**[Client Side Code]**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://IPADDRESS:3001');
$('#chat').on('submit', function (e) { //2
    var msg = $('#message').val();
    if (!msg) return;
    socket.emit('send:message', {
        message: msg
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message').val('')
    $('.msg_history').append(`<div class="outgoing_msg"><div class="sent_msg"><p>${msg}</p><span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div></div>`);
});
// Receive a message
socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
    $('.msg_history').append(`<div class="incoming_msg"><div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"></div><div class="received_msg"><div class="received_withd_msg"><p>${data}</p><span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div></div></div>`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket io broadcasts message throughout all application so you receive your message also.

so when you send a message send with sender id and receiver id.

```
socket.emit('send:message', {
        message: msg,
        sender_id: 'YOUR USER ID'
});
```

Whenever you are receiving the message you have to check sender id and match with your own id if sender id does not match append the message otherwise leave it.

```
socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
if(data.sender_id!='YOUR USER ID'){
$('.msg_history').append(`
<div class="incoming_msg"> 
    <div class="incoming_msg_img">
        <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">
    </div> 
    <div class="received_msg"> 
       <div class="received_withd_msg"> 
           <p>${data}</p> 
           <span class="time_date"> 
                11:01 AM    |    June 9
           </span> 
       </div> 
    </div> 
</div> `);}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! Problem Solved with this solution

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you, change your emit name on server or client. for example in server

```
socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
      io.sockets.to('sangumee-Quarterican-KJ').emit('receive:message', data.message);
      console.log(data.message);
    });
```

and on client:

```
socket.on('receive:message', function (data) {
    $('.msg_history').append(`<div class="incoming_msg"><div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"></div><div class="received_msg"><div class="received_withd_msg"><p>${data}</p><span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div></div></div>`);
});
```